# Django - How do to subtract two annotations with different models

Tags: python, django

```
a = Category.objects.annotate(total_products=Count('product'))
b=Order.objects.values('category__name').annotate(total_approve=Sum('approve_quantity')).order_by('-total_approve')
```

**so I want to subtract a - b**.

Both annotations works fine but how to reduce the total_products in a category when a specific quantity is approved is the challenge. Is there a different way ?

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    reorder_level = models.IntegerField(default='0', blank=True, 
        null=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True, 
        null=True)
```

```
class Product(models.Model):
    pro_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey('Order',default='', on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True)
    serial_num = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    model_num = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    storage_size = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    memory_size = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    receive_quantity = models.IntegerField(default='0', blank=True, null=True)
    issue_by = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    issue_to = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False, null=True) 
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True, null=True)
```

```py
class Order(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        null=True)
    pro_name = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        null=True,related_name='product') 
    staff = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    order_quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=DEPARTMENT, null=True)
    order_status = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    approve_quantity = models.IntegerField(default='1', blank=True, null=True)
    transaction_id = models.CharField(default=uuid.uuid4().hex[:8].upper(), max_length=50, editable=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True, null=True)
```

Comment: Please share your models.

Comment: did you want to subtract total_products - total_approve?

Comment: @Zilay yes i want to

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i have added the models

Comment: @DavisFila: I assume you have a `Product` model with a `ForeignKey` to `Category`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem:  Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can annotate the `Category`s with a [**`Subquery`** expression <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions):

```
from django.db.models import Count, F, OuterRef, Subquery, Sum

Category.objects.annotate(
    total_products=Count('product'),
    total_approve=Subquery(
        Order.objects.filter(
            category=OuterRef('pk')
        ).values('category').annotate(
            total=Sum('approve_quantity')
        ).order_by('category').values('total')[:1]
    )
).annotate(
    difference=F('total_products')-F('total_approve')
)
```

The `Category` objects that arise from this queryset will have an extra attribute `.difference` that will contain the difference between the number of related `Product`s, and the total of the `approved_quantity`s for the related `Order`s.